# Making a Datum from a Data Set, Stanford NLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I was trying to run through examples for the Stanford NLP Classifier and had a question about classifying a new data set. I see that the ".test" file contains the "goldClass" which is the right answer as well as the String which is supposed to be tested.

The example test set has the following format:

```
<label> <string>
<label> <String>
...
....
```

This makes sense for evaluation of a model once we a model has been created from a hand classified data set. But now, once a model is created, how do I classify a completely new data set? I no longer have the associated Labels... I just have the new set of strings that I want to know the class for...

But to classify them, I will have to create a Datum object. To create a datum object, I will need to use makeDatumFromLine(), which requires a TSV line...  WHY does this have to be TSV? What is the use of specifying a goldClass when classifying new data?

I hope my question was clear..

Comment: I'm trying to work out exactly the same thing - I can't find any way to classify a new item.

Answer (score 0):

"Why does it have to be TSV?"

Because it does. My solution to get the class of an unknown line is the following:

```
    Datum<String, String> example = cdc.makeDatumFromLine("\tEverybody here needs food badly!");
System.out.println("Example data-> "+cl.classOf(example));
```

Seems to work fine. I don't know if this is the best use- but it works for me.

Comment: "*Because it does*." Please try to be a *bit* more specific when answering. Perhaps reference a source to back up your claim.

Comment: http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/ColumnDataClassifier.html
The way this class parses is in a column format- by default its tab-separated. There appears to be options to use CSV, but I find setting the non-standard options is a non-trivial exercise, so would recommend leaving it as is.